# Debug Multi-Dimensional Arrays C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

Is there a way to display the matrix as a table in debug mode? I think that how VS 2019 show it isn't relevant to see how the matrix changes.

[image: Visual Studio 2019]
[image: table]

Comment: "...to see the changes"? What do you want to see?

Comment: [Custom visualizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-visualizers-of-data)? [Tutorial](https://wrightfully.com/writing-a-readonly-debugger-visualizer).

Comment: @HimBromBeere, how the matrix changes.

Comment: As @Sinatr said, custom visualizer. You might try looking for something matching your needs on the Visual Studio marketplace. (Random pick, no endorsement: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AmirLiberman.ArrayVisualizer) **EDIT**: Oh, i just noticed that my random pick is officially not supported for VS2019 (yet). Well, if it ain't working in VS2019, then i guess you would need to search for another one then... Bummer! :-(

Comment: @Sinatr, thank you for your response but I am a beginner, and it will be hard for me to set up this.

Comment: @elgonzo, this was exactly what I wanted, but it's for Visual Studio 2010, 2012, 2013, 2015.

Comment: @NikolDimitrova, yeah i just noticed and edited my comment accordingly. I'm sorry about that. What if you just try it in VS2019 (i am not using VS2019 myself, so i can't tell). If it doesn't work, i guess you need to look around on the marketplace a bit and see if there is something for your needs :-(

Comment: @elgonzo, I'd searched before I posted this, but I didn't find anything. https://amirliberman.gallerycdn.vsassets.io/extensions/amirliberman/arrayvisualizer/1.4.0.0/1482137609157/72889/1/ArrVis2D.PNG This is what I'm searching for.

Comment: @elgonzo, I tried it - it isn't working. I can't install it.

Comment: @NikolDimitrova, yeah that is a screenshot from the visualizer i suggested in my comment. It seems there is not much on the marketplace specifically for VS2019. I am sorry that i wasn't be more helpful,  :-(

Comment: @elgonzo, I'll wait if someone could suggest something good.

Comment: @Sinatr From your link to the docs -> "You can write a custom visualizer for an object of any managed class except for Object and Array." even if OP was experienced enough, it still wouldn't work in this case.

Comment: This is post is for VS 2005. I'm using VS 2019. I don't know what's the point of your comment. It's useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a simple [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) to a project you are debugging:

```
public static class DebugExtensions
{
    public static string Test2D(this Array source, int pad = 10)
    {
        var result = "";
        for (int i = source.GetLowerBound(0); i <= source.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = source.GetLowerBound(1); j <= source.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
                result += source.GetValue(i, j).ToString().PadLeft(pad);
            result += "\n";
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

This method is iterating through 2 dimensional array adding each array item to a multi-line string.

While debugging you can use it in [Watch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/watch-and-quickwatch-windows) window. Open `Watch` window, type new expression, click on magnifier icon and choose "Text Visualizer":

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response! Where should I add this code?

Comment: And how can I run it? Sorry! I am not very experienced with C#.

Comment: Could you help me?

Comment: I got it! Thank you. Can I use it while testing the program or I must open it after every update of the matrix?

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Sinatr works great. You can also use it in a slightly different way.

While debugging, set a breakpoint after the declaration of your array and go to the Immediate Window. In the Immediate Window, type `Debug.WriteLine(myArray.Test2D())` and it will show you the output right then and there.

You can also replace `return result;` with `Debug.WriteLine(result);` and change the return type to `void` so you don't have to write the `Debug.WriteLine()`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34623895)